# x is not a valid date/time component for function DATEADD

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dateadd

Both of these syntaxes work (with and without the quotes)

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), DATEADD('hour', -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Now, I want to to use 'hour' in a stored procedure like this. I used the `varchar` type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "EXECUTE_INSERT_TEST"(hour_or_date varchar, Load_day_number number, load_day_from timestamp)
RETURNS NUMBER(38,0)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 'begin
INSERT INTO TABLE_1
(FILE_NAME, LOAD_DATE)
SELECT FILE_NAME, LOAD_DATE
FROM TABLE_2
     where 1 = 1  
       and LOAD_DATE >= DATEADD(hour_or_date, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
;
  RETURN 1;
end';
```

However, when I try to run the procedure,

```
CALL "EXECUTE_INSERT_TEST"('hour', -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

I get this error:

```
SQL Error [2151] [22023]: Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 3 at position 0 : SQL compilation error: ['HOUR_OR_DATE'] is not a valid date/time component for function DATEADD.
```

How else can I pass the hour or date types as parameters?

Comment: I don't think this will work, the `hour_or_date` is interpreted as a unit name (which then fails, as there is no such unit), not as a reference to the variable `hour_or_date`. I don't think you can pass this as a variable.

Comment: but isn't it the arg_name? Can't we use anything as the arg_name? ```CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] PROCEDURE <name> ( [ <arg_name> <arg_data_type> ] [ , ... ] )``` https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-procedure.html @MarkRotteveel

Comment: DATEADD(:hour_or_date,-1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), try binding the variable by adding **:** in front of it as **:hour_or_date**. This should do it.

Comment: still the same error. am i calling the procedure correctly? @Sergiu

Comment: I don't know Snowflake, but I guess that the fact you can pass a string literal like `'hour'` instead of the token `hour` is just a parser trick, and likely it doesn't allow parameters, variables or anything else there.

Comment: I am already passing in a string. Do you mean I should pass in " 'hour' "? What would be the syntax for that? @MarkRotteveel. I also get the same errors if I tried to do the same thin with the second argument (number)

Comment: I mean the fact you can use a string **literal** in `DATEADD('hour', ...` is likely just a parser trick (it probably has a syntax rule that treats `hour` and `'hour'` the same, and for other units). It doesn't necessarily mean that you can pass a parameter, variable or anything else there. Or maybe Snowflake requires you to prefix parameters in a statement, e.g. by using `:hour_or_date`, or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use snowflake scripted procedure with binding.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-snowflake-scripting.html

like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEMP."EXECUTE_INSERT_TEST"(hour_or_date varchar, Load_day_number number, load_day_from timestamp)
RETURNS NUMBER(38,0)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE_1(FILE_NAME, LOAD_DATE)
    SELECT FILE_NAME, LOAD_DATE
    FROM TABLE_2
    where 1 = 1  
      and LOAD_DATE >= DATEADD(:hour_or_date, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);   
    RETURN 1;  
 END;
$$

CALL "EXECUTE_INSERT_TEST"('hour', -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEMP.table_2 ( file_name varchar(55), load_date timestamp);
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEMP.table_1 ( file_name varchar(55), load_date timestamp);

INSERT INTO table_2
SELECT 'some_file',current_timestamp();
```